# Unexpected results from user input calculations in Shiny reactive functions

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Some of the calculations in the reactive environment of the below Shiny reprex have been stumping me for a while now, and I am hoping that I can find a solution here. This app takes four user inputs from the sidebar panel and calculates the output table based on two sets of multiplier tables (that are created at the top of the app). For each set of these inputs, three values are calculated - expenditure_calc, salary_calc and emp_calc - based on the sector/subsector multiplier tables. For a given Sector input (first drop-down), if an "Unknown subsector" is selected from the second drop-down box, the sector_multiplier_table is used for calculations. And, when one of Subsector 1, Subsector 2... is chosen, the subsector_multiplier_table" is used.

For example, for the below user inputs, Select sector: Sector 1; Select subsector: Subsector 1; Calculation based on: Expenditure; Value: 2,000,000, the resulting calculations based on the subsector multiplier table are: expenditure_calc = 2,000,000; salary_calc = 400,000; emp_calc = 10

The calculations seem to be working fine in most cases, but when I choose a combination of sectors/subsectors involving "Unknown subsector", they are giving me values that I fail to comprehend. Here is an example of inputs that results in incorrect calculations:

Input selection 1: "Sector 1", "Subsector 1", "Expenditure", 1000000 Input selection 2: "Sector 1", "Unknown subsector", "Emp", 24

Any help is appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dashboardthemes)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Sector multiplier table
sector <- c("Sector 1", "Sector 2", "Sector 3")
expenditure <- c(1000000, 1000000, 1000000)
salary <- c(250000, 500000, 160000)
emp <- c(5, 7, 9)
sector_multipliers <- data.frame(sector, expenditure, salary, emp)

# Subsector multiplier table
sector <- c("Sector 1", "Sector 1", "Sector 1", "Sector 1", "Sector 2", "Sector 2", "Sector 2", "Sector 3", "Sector 3")
subsector <- c("Subsector 1", "Subsector 2", "Subsector 3", "Subsector 4", "Subsector 1", "Subsector 2", "Subsector 3", "Subsector 1", "Subsector 2")
expenditure <- c(1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000)
salary <- c(200000, 250000, 300000, 400000, 425000, 280000, 600000, 170000, 150000)
emp <- c(5, 7, 9, 12, 9, 14, 18, 4, 5)
subsector_multipliers <- data.frame(sector, subsector, expenditure, salary, emp)

# Initialize empty data frame to store user input
input_data <- data.frame(sector = character(), subsector = character(), calc_type = character(), calc_value = double(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# UI component
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "Calculations", titleWidth = 450),
  # UI sidebar panel
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    minified = F, 
    width = 300,
    pickerInput("sector", 
                "Select sector:",
                choices = sector_multipliers$sector,
                options = list(`live-search` = TRUE, title = "Select a sector", selected = NULL)),
    pickerInput("subsector", 
                "Select subsector:", 
                choices = "",
                options = list(`live-search` = TRUE, title = "Select a subsector", selected = NULL)),
    radioButtons("calc_type",
                 label = "Calculation based on:", 
                 choices = list("Expenditure", "Emp"),
                 selected = "Expenditure"),
    numericInput("calc_value", 
                 "Enter value:", 
                 value = "1000000"),
    actionButton("add_btn",
                 "Add Values"),
    actionButton("delete_btn",
                 "Delete Values"),
    actionButton("calculate_btn", 
                 "CALCULATE")
  ),
  
  # UI body
  body = dashboardBody(
    
    tabPanel(
      "Model input and calculations",
      fluidRow(tags$h5("Input selections:"),
               actionButton("reset", "Clear All"),
               DT::dataTableOutput("input_table")),
      br(),
      fluidRow(tags$h5("Sector or subsector table join multipliers that are used:"),
               DT::dataTableOutput("multipliers_join")
      ),
      br(),
      fluidRow(tags$h5("Multiplier calculation output:"), 
               DT::dataTableOutput("calculation_output"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Populating subsector drop-down after a sector is selected  
  observeEvent(
    input$sector,
    updatePickerInput(session, "subsector", "Select Subsector:",
                      choices = c("Unknown subsector", subsector_multipliers$subsector[subsector_multipliers$sector == input$sector]))
  )
  
  # Creating reactive shock table from user inputs
  input_table <- reactiveVal(input_data)
  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
    # req(input$sector, input$subsector, input$calc_type, input$calc_value)
    t = rbind(input_table(), data.frame(sector = input$sector, subsector = input$subsector, calc_type = input$calc_type, calc_value = input$calc_value))
    input_table(t)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delete_btn, {
    t = input_table()
    print(input$input_table_rows_selected)
    if (!is.null(input$input_table_rows_selected)) {
      t <- t[-input$input_table_rows_selected,]
    }
    input_table(t)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    input_table(input_data)
  })
  
  output$input_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(input_table(), selection = 'single', editable = F,
              colnames = c("Sector", "Subsector", "Expenditure/Emp", "Value"),
              options = list(paging = TRUE)) %>% 
      formatCurrency(columns = c(4), currency = "", interval = 3, mark = ",", digits = 0)
  })
  
  
  # Change input multiplier join tables based on subsector selection
  # If subsector is "Unknown subsector" use the sector multiplier table
  sector_multipliers_join <- eventReactive(input$calculate_btn, {
    input_table() %>% 
      filter(input_table()[[2]] == "Unknown subsector") %>% 
      left_join(sector_multipliers)
  })
  
  # If subsector is selected use the subsector multiplier table
  subsector_multipliers_join <- eventReactive(input$calculate_btn, {
    input_table() %>% 
      filter(input_table()[[2]] != "Unknown subsector") %>% 
      left_join(subsector_multipliers)
  })
  
  # Bind shock multiplier tables for unknown and known subsectors
  multipliers_join <- reactive({
    bind_rows(sector_multipliers_join(), subsector_multipliers_join())
  }) 
  output$multipliers_join <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(multipliers_join()))
  
  # Calculations
  calculation_output <- eventReactive(input$calculate_btn, {
    req(input$sector, input$subsector, input$calc_type, input$calc_value)
    multipliers_join() %>% 
      mutate(
        expenditure_calc = if_else(input_table()[[3]] == "Expenditure", ((calc_value * expenditure) / expenditure),
                                            ((calc_value * expenditure) / emp))) %>%
      mutate(
        salary_calc = if_else(input_table()[[3]] == "Expenditure", ((calc_value * salary) / expenditure),
                                       ((calc_value * salary) / emp))) %>%
      mutate(
        emp_calc = if_else(input_table()[[3]] == "Expenditure", ((calc_value * emp) / expenditure),
                                    ((calc_value * emp) / emp)))
  })
  
  output$calculation_output <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(calculation_output())
  })
  
} # End of server logic

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here.

1. When checking for a value in a vector, you should use `%in%` instead of `==`
2. In the `calculation_output`, you are trying to compare a vector from a different table to a specific value and assigning a value to a new variable. It may not be in the same order. As you have a column named `calc_type` in the same table, you could use that column.

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Populating subsector drop-down after a sector is selected  
  observeEvent(
    input$sector,
    updatePickerInput(session, "subsector", "Select Subsector:",
                      choices = c("Unknown subsector", subsector_multipliers$subsector[subsector_multipliers$sector == input$sector]))
  )
  
  # Creating reactive shock table from user inputs
  input_table <- reactiveVal(input_data)
  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
    # req(input$sector, input$subsector, input$calc_type, input$calc_value)
    t = rbind(input_table(), data.frame(sector = input$sector, subsector = input$subsector, calc_type = input$calc_type, calc_value = input$calc_value))
    input_table(t)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delete_btn, {
    t = input_table()
    print(input$input_table_rows_selected)
    if (!is.null(input$input_table_rows_selected)) {
      t <- t[-input$input_table_rows_selected,]
    }
    input_table(t)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    input_table(input_data)
  })
  
  output$input_tabl <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(input_table(), selection = 'single', editable = F,
              colnames = c("Sector", "Subsector", "Expenditure/Emp", "Value"),
              options = list(paging = TRUE)) %>% 
      formatCurrency(columns = c(4), currency = "", interval = 3, mark = ",", digits = 0)
  })
  
  
  ###  Change input multiplier join tables based on subsector selection
  ###  If subsector is "Unknown subsector" use the sector multiplier table
  sector_multipliers_join <- eventReactive(input$calculate_btn, {
    input_table() %>%
      dplyr::filter(input_table()[[2]] %in% "Unknown subsector") %>%
      #dplyr::filter(sum(input_table()[[2]] %in% "Unknown subsector")>0) %>%
      left_join(sector_multipliers)
  })

  ### If subsector is selected use the subsector multiplier table
  subsector_multipliers_join <- eventReactive(input$calculate_btn, {
    input_table() %>%
      dplyr::filter(!input_table()[[2]] %in% "Unknown subsector") %>%
      left_join(subsector_multipliers)
  })

  
  # Bind shock multiplier tables for unknown and known subsectors
  multipliers_join <- reactive({
    bind_rows(sector_multipliers_join(), subsector_multipliers_join())
  }) 
  output$multipliers_join <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(multipliers_join()))
  
  # Calculations
  calculation_output <- eventReactive(input$calculate_btn, {
    req(input$sector, input$subsector, input$calc_type, input$calc_value)
    multipliers_join()  %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(
        expenditure_calc = ifelse(calc_type %in% "Expenditure", ((calc_value * expenditure) / expenditure),
                                   ((calc_value * expenditure) / emp))) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(
        salary_calc = ifelse(calc_type %in% "Expenditure", ((calc_value * salary) / expenditure),
                              ((calc_value * salary) / emp))) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(
        emp_calc = ifelse(calc_type %in% "Expenditure", ((calc_value * emp) / expenditure),
                           ((calc_value * emp) / emp)))
  })
  
  output$calculation_output <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(calculation_output())
  })
  
} # End of server logic
```

Comment: Your suggestions work @YBS. As per your second comment, could you please elaborate on why comparing a vector from a different table does not work and why "it may not be in the same order?"

Comment: You can try with your previous code. Sometimes, the order in `multipliers_join()` was `c("Expenditure", "Emp")`, and the order in `input_table()` was reverse.  This order makes a difference in the `ifelse(...)` verification. You could make it work by sorting both tables to be in the same order prior to this operation. That is the reason you noticed no issue when there is only one selection (row).

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand it now.